# Getting text in <div> using Selenium

Tags: html, selenium

I have a question related to Selenium in Python:

I want to obtain the text content "D. New Jersey" on a webpage. In addition, the text that I want to get can be different on different pages, but it is always under "**COURT:**".

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="span4">
  <strong>COURT:</strong>
  D. New Jersey
</div>
```

The code I use now is as follows. And it doesn't work.

```
self.driver.get(address) 
element=driver.findElement("//a[contains(@class,'span4') and contains(div/div/text(),'COURT:')]").gettext()
```

I have also tried the following solutions with no luck, and no Selenium exception is being thrown either:

```
text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[strong[text()='COURT:']]").text
```

and

```
text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'span4') and contains(div/div/text(),'COURT:')]").text
```

Is there anyone who knows how to get the text from this code using Selenium?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Hi Austen. There is no way that I am fishing any code here lol. I simply wanted to be straight to the point. The code I use is : self.driver.get(address)
            element=driver.findElement("//a[contains(@class,'span4') and contains(div/div/text(),'COURT:')]").gettext()  However it simply doesn't work out.

Comment: If you could edit your question to add that code, that would make it much easier for someone to be able to assist you.

Comment: Advice adopted.

Comment: In Python, web elements do not support a `gettext()` function -- you just need to use `text`, an attribute. I've added a solution using the `text` attribute along with a refined XPath to help with your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python, you can get the text as such:

```
text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[strong[text()='COURT:']]").text
```

This uses an XPath to query on the `div` element, using its inner `strong` element to ensure we have selected the correct `div`. Then, we call Python's `webelement.text` method to get the `div`'s text.

Comment: Hi Christine. I tried your solution, and added print(text). However, Python doesn't seem to print anything and get the text I wanted...

Comment: Can you try printing the WebElement to see if it's been located? `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[strong[text()='COURT:']]")`, followed by `print(element)`

Comment: It seems like the element is not getting located correctly. Is there any exception being thrown or error message in the console? Selenium usually throws a NoSuchElement exception if you are trying to find something that does not exist. and that error should display in the console. I've updated my solution to use the original XPath you posted in your question -- let's see if that makes a difference.

Comment: No, there is simply nothing prompted on the screen. There's no error message.

Comment: Again, using my original code with .text doesn't throw anything either...

Comment: I noticed your original sample uses `self.driver.get(url)` to navigate to a url, but you are not referencing `self.driver` when you try to find an element, just `driver.` Updated my answer to use `self.driver` to see if that helps. If `self.driver` is working to navigate to the URL, it should work to find a web element as well.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is here. If `self.driver.get(url)` works correctly, and `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)` does not throw a `NoSuchElement` exception, then there's probably something else happening in the code that is not visible from your sample. Even if the XPath is incorrect, Selenium still throws an exception when an element is not located. The fact that you are not seeing any error messages whatsoever is concerning.

Comment: Oh I just noticed that I used try: except: pass in my original code. Thats the reason why no error message was thrown. Now I removed 'try'. Python gives me this message : Message: Unable to locate element: //a[contains(div/div/text(),'COURT:')]

Comment: It works now!!! text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[strong[text()='COURT:']]").text I ll approve your solution

Comment: That makes sense that the exception was being hidden in the try / except block. I usually remove those blocks from my code for debugging purposes, so that I can see helpful error messages as such. Glad to see you've got your solution working here.