# selenium find element xpath

Tags: selenium, text, element

I have a question related to Selenium.
I want to get the text "DISSMISSED" from a webpage. however I tried the following codes and it doesn't work or cannot locate the element.

```
text7 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/@class='icon-check']").text
```

or

```
text7 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[strong[text()='Case Status']]").text
```

Here is the html code:

```
<p>
 <strong>Case Status:  </strong>
 <span class="icon-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 DISMISSED
 <span> </span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting text in <div> using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290528/getting-text-in-div-using-selenium). Check in [about xpath](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Comment: @Sers its actually a follow up question. I didnt manage to get the result I want using the method in the other post.

Comment: One more resource to learn basics https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you want to get is in between the `<p></p>` tag, then

`//span[@class='icon-check']/parent::p`

with this simple xpath you can get the **DISMISSED** text.

Comment: Oh that works like a miracle. I ll approve your solution. But what does "/parent::p" stand for?

Comment: parent means you have <span> tag under <p> tag then the <p> tag is parent of <span> tag.

Answer (score 1):

If HTML is as below:

```
<HTML>
<Body>
  <p>
 <strong>Case Status:  </strong>
 <span class="icon-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 DISMISSED
 <span> </span>
 </p>
</Body>
</HTML>
```

That means text `DISMISSED` belongs to p tag

So try that

```
//p/strong[contains(.,'Case Status')]/following-sibling::span/..
```

OR

```
//p[contains(.,'DISMISSED')]/strong[contains(.,'Case Status')]/following-sibling::span/..
```